# Empaquetar aplicación Python con PyInstaller

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyinstaller

Tengo una aplicación en Python 2.7 que quiero empaquetar usando PyInstaller pero al crearse el .exe no se abre correctamente.

La aplicacion tiene un archivo `____init____.py` y utiliza 9 scripts python para validaciones, conexion a la BD, modulos de procesos, etc, también utiliza imágenes (.gif) y hojas de calculo excel (.xlsx) para el proceso de la aplicación.

Al crearse la carpeta DIST debo copiar manualmente en ella todos estos archivos que la aplicación necesita ([image: Este Error aparece al no copiar los archivos manualmente])  y la aplicación funciona correctamente de manera local, pero al ejecutarla en otra computadora no funciona [image: y aparece este error]

El archivo inicial tiene una interfaz de inicio de sesion hecha con Tkinter y al pulsar un boton hace conexion con la base de datos Oracle mediante la libreria CX_ORACLE y continua la ejecucion de la aplicacion.

¿Hay alguna manera de empaquetar y crear el .exe con todos los archivos mediante la ventana de comandos?

El comando que estoy utilizando en la consola es:

```
pyinstaller --onefile __init__.py
```

la versión de pyinstaller es 3.2.1

Comment: ¿Que significa "No se abre correctamente"?  ¿podrías editar tu pregunta y agregar más información al respecto, por ej. eventuales errores o descripción del funcionamiento?

Comment: Tal y como dice Patricio haría falta algo de más información, te aconsejo usar la opcion `--debug` y habilitar la consola en la aplicación para no ocultar posibles errores en tiempo de ejecución. Muestra la salida de debug y posibles excepciones durante la ejecución mostradas en la consola. Saludos.

Comment: @FJSevilla es correcto, quitando la opcion **--noconsole** se muestra la consola y obtengo la salida, sin embargo no soluciona mi problema, he colocado los switches **--add-data** y **--hidden-import** para intentar añadir e importar los archivos y modulos que usa la aplicacion pero tampoco soluciona mi problema. Ya no se que mas hacer

Comment: Lo que no entiendo es: la maquina remota tiene un Oracle ?

Comment: Si @leonbloy la maquina local donde desarrollé la aplicacion tiene Oracle 10g instalada. 
La instalé para ir haciendo las pruebas del programa y no tocar la BD oficial donde se iba a instalar la aplicacion.
Al finalizar todo, conecte la aplicacion con la BD final que alimenta al programa pero como ves, no corre en las demas máquinas

Comment: Mirate esta pregunta del sitio en ingés a ver si te ayuda: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36478831/pyinstaller-cx-oracle-interfaceerror-unable-to-acquire-oracle-environment-hand

Comment: Yo no creo que sea un problema de Python o pyinstaller, me da la impresión de que la máquina remota no tiene Oracle instalado. pyinstaller puede crear un exe, pero lo que no puede hacer es "detectar" dependencias externas como una base de datos Oracle, deduciendo que debe instalar Oracle: eso vas a tener que distribuirlo tú mismo junto con tu programa.

Comment: El problema es que tcl/tk tiene librería externas, deberías agregar las dll en la carpeta del exe generado para que funcione correctamente.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar tambien [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial)

Es muy sencillo y solo tienes que crear un archivo setup, donde le puedes indicar las dll que necesitas, librerias para que esten empaquetadas, si quieres que tenga el terminal al lado de la aplicación, etc.

Y despues solo ejecutar:

```
python setup.py py2exe
```

Puedes indicar que empaquete tambien imágenes:

```
# setup.py
from distutils.core import setup
import glob
import py2exe
setup(console=["myscript.py"],
  data_files=[("bitmaps",
               ["bm/large.gif", "bm/small.gif"]),
              ("fonts",
               glob.glob("fonts\\*.fnt"))],
)
```

En este [enlace](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/ListOfOptions), estan más opciones.

Answer (score 0):

Respecto al primer error:

Tuve un problema similar en python 3, pero el error era el mismo, en tu caso es con un archivo.gif.

La forma en que lo solucione facilmente fue agregando el archivo manualmente en la carpeta del programa generada dentro de 'dist'