# Como hacer un proyecto en Python 100% portable?

Tags: python

tengo un proyecto en `Python` y necesito hacerlo portable. El problema es que cuando convierto la carpeta en un `zip`, y ejecuto esos archivos en otra PC, el interprete no busca los paquetes en el `entorno virtual` de la carpeta, sino en la misma PC, eso hace que me de error cuando ejecuto el proyecto otras PC aun cuando si tengo las dependencias necesarias para ejecutar. Que puedo hacer?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Empaquetar aplicación Python con PyInstaller](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/83352/empaquetar-aplicaci%c3%b3n-python-con-pyinstaller)

Comment: ¿En el zip estás incorporando también la carpeta del entorno virtual? una vez descomprimido, al ejecutar,  ¿activaste el entorno virtual antes?

Comment: @Alfabravo probablemente no, ya que podría referirse a ofrecer el programa sin instalador ni exe.